# SQL query from three tables, using the results from the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with queries from multiple tables. My platform is SQL. The first two columns of each table (ID, Tag) are related to each other. I am trying to select data from table2 and table3 using the results from table1.

[image: Table1.ID, Tag, Top Weight, Bottom Weight, Total Weight]
[image: Table2.ID, Tag, Color, Shade, Tint, Transparancy]
[image: Table3.ID, Tag, Sequence, Length, Width, Height]

Table1 is used to determine the ID and Tag. The combination of ID and Tag is unique for this table. There are no null values in table1. In this example, I will search for the ID and Tag using the Top Weight and Bottom Weight. However, any number of criteria can be used to find the ID and Tag.

```
SELECT ID, Tag FROM table1 WHERE Top Weight = '22' AND Bottom Weight = '44'
```

[image: Table1 query results]

I would like to take the ID and Tag results from table1, and use them for my table2 and table3 queries. For table2, the combination of the first two columns (ID, Tag) is unique. I would like to select Color, Shade, and Tint from this table. There can be null values for these columns. For table3, the combination of the first three columns (ID, Tag, Sequence) is unique. I would like to select Sequence, Length, and Width from this table. These columns can also have null values.

Is it possible to combine all three tables into a single query, and use the results of the first table to get the results of the second and third table? The example tables are only 14 rows, but in reality, there are tens of thousands of rows – so performance is critical (when is it not?). I look forward to your response, thanks.

Comment: I am sorry - it is SQL Server. I was playing around with MS Access for the screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a fairly straightforward outer join query:

```
select t1.id, t1.tag,
       t2.Color, t2.Shade, t2.Tint,
       t3.Sequence, t3.Length, t3.Width
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.tag = t2.tag
left join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.id and t1.tag = t3.tag
WHERE t1.[Top Weight] = '22' AND t1.[Bottom Weight] = '44'
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark - is there a possibility of using subqueries as an alternative solution?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it is not recommended.

Comment: @JohnK: As Katona says, you can but it is not a good idea. Why would you want to? Do you want to see the results for t2 on separate rows to the results for t3 ?

Comment: I was just thinking if I only require one column from the second or third table, instead of multiple columns. Its a little out of scope from my original description.

Comment: @JohnK: Even if it's only one column, performance is generally better using a join than a sub-query (where you can achieve the same result with a straight join).